# LocalBroadcastManager not working

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

I'm trying to sendMessage from service to activity, but for some reason it's not working.

Activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode);
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));


private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            Boolean state = intent.getBooleanExtra("state",false);
            if(state){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Данные успешно отправлены",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Service

```
   private void sendMessage(boolean state) {
        Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
        Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("state", state);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Log.d "broadcasting message" is shown and then nothing happens

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

In android manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".service.TerminalService"
    android:process=":update_service" >
</service>
```

It seems when android:process is specified localbroadcastmanager is not working. I just deleted android:process line and it worked

Comment: are you sure that `state` is true? Also, use native type whenever is possible, change from `Boolean state` to `boolean state`

Comment: `onReceive ` method executing or not ?

Comment: intent.putExtra("state", state); what is state variable value ?

Comment: onReceive is not called that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing  wrong with your code .only update your receive method  `else` clause

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Get extra data included in the Intent
                Boolean state = intent.getBooleanExtra("state",false);
                if(state){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Данные успешно отправлены",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"else message ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }
            }
        };
```

Comment: onReceive method is not called at all

Comment: it is solved, the reason it was not working is in manifest         <service
            android:name=".service.TerminalService"
            android:process=":update_service" >
        </service>

Answer (score -2):

com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager -> change
androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0

Comment: That is too terse to understand.